# Display Modal on Successful Form Submission

Tags: javascript, forms, zurb-foundation, kentico

I'm using a Kentico form to collect some data and I'd like to display a Foundation modal upon successful submission. We have some validation on the fields and we'd prefer to use an update panel to prevent a postback.

We were able to get the modal to display by inserting a div with an id in the display text and having some javascript that checks for its existence but that only works if we don't use an update panel.

I'm thinking there's probably a way to get the modal to display with the update panel but I'm not sure what the best approach would be and looking for suggestions.

Comment: You can dynamically set the content and trigger the `open` method. See https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html#ajax

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you're using is fine, the only issue, if I understood correctly is that javascript code responsible for showing popup does not recognize form submission when there is update panel - are you listening document ready event handler? if so you need to add another event handler that listens to update panel requests. It should be something like:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (prm != null) {
        prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
        ....
        }
     }
```

I hope that helps